# How do I convert all python operations involving None to None values?

Tags: python, nonetype

I want all mathematical operations involving one or more None variables to return None.

Example:

```
a = None
b = 7
a*b
```

I want this last line to return None, but it instead gives me an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

I understand why this error exists and all that, but is there any way to force the result to be just a `None`?

**Background**: I have a few functions that mine data and return a value, called `diff`. Later on I multiply or add `diff` to a few things to get meaningful information, but not all of my original data contains a useful `diff`, so I have it set to return `diff = None` in these cases. I want to be able to skip over these points when I'm plotting results. Python seems to have no trouble skipping over `None` elements in an array when I'm plotting, so I'd like to just have the results of the operations be `None`.

Comment: Use a float("NaN") rather than `None`

Comment: [How to chain attribute lookups that might return None?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15280511); [Maybe "kind of" monad in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8507200),

Comment: Similar to @donkopotamus you can use the decimal module and `decimal.Decimal('NaN')` for `None`. This may be preferable if you want correctly-rounded decimal arithmetic. If all of your operations use `Decimal` numbers it will work the way you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of trying to force all mathematical operations that contain some arbitrary other value to return that arbitrary other value, you could simply use a [`NaN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), which is designed for exactly this sort of purpose:

```
>>> nan = float("NaN")
>>> 7 * nan
nan
>>> 7 + nan
nan
```

A `nan` will correctly cascade throughout your mathematical operations.

A good plotting library will also understand `nan` and omit them at plot time.  But if not, simply do your replacement of `NaN` to `None` immediately prior to plotting.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for presence of `None` in arguments and then return early:

```
def calc(*args, **kwargs):
    if None in list(args) + list(kwargs.keys()):
        return None
    #rest
```

You can also write a decorator and wrap the existing functions, this would be more useful if you want to apply this operation to many existing functions (or even just one, for clarity):

```
def return_none_for_none(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return None if None in list(args) + list(kwargs.keys()) else f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


@return_none_for_none
def some_math_exp(a, b, c=2):
    return a + b*c
```

Comment: Why not simply use two membership checks with `if None in args or None in kwargs` rather than creating a list out of each and then combining them into a third?

Comment: Why would you check if `None` is a **key** in `kwargs`?

Answer (score 0):

Without having much context to your code structure; I assume you just want to try an operation, and return None if it's not possible.

Perhaps a try/except could work here:

```
try:
    # operation here
except TypeError:
    return None
```

However I do agree with **@donkopotamus** using a `NaN` float value accomplishes exactly what you're looking for. If the expression you're try to evaluate contains a `NaN` then the entire expressions evaluates to `NaN`. You could always return `None` if `NaN` is found, or convert your data when passing it to the math library.

```
>>> nan = float('NaN')
>>> nan + 15 ** 4
nan
>>> 1000 - nan /6%3
nan
>>>
```

Comment: Being pedantic, a `nan` will not always cause a parent expression to evaluate to `nan`.  Consider `1**nan` or `nan**1`.  All these rules for cascade have been carefully thought of by others, we need not second guess ;-)